# Qt python adjust position widget dynamically

Tags: pyqt

I have a tablewidget with 10 columns. Some of them are prices and I want to get the sum of each of this numeric columns above the tablewidget in doublespinbox fields.
It would be easier to get them in a new (and last) line in the tablewidget bit i would have to scroll down at the end of the tablewidget.
It would be stange to get them at the first line of the tablewidget.
The problem is that the witdh of the columns are depending from the length of the text (as the 'product description' field for example) since I emit a 'resizeToContents' after having fullfilled the tablewidget.
When the width of the columns change, the doublespinbox fields are no longer above the numeric fields. Does anybody have an idea how I can solve this ?

Comment: Why a double spinbox? Do you want to adjust the sum of each column somehow? Why not a simple label?

Comment: What you seem to be asking for is a frozen row/column. The Qt docs have an [example for columns](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-itemviews-frozencolumn-example.html), and the same approach could be used for rows. Basically, it involves glueing two tables together and synchronizing them using various signals. If you do a web-search for `qt table frozen row` you should find some other examples.

Answer (score 0):

Well... I'm not entirely sure what you are asking but if being able to change the width of columns manually, you can do

```
table.setColumnWidth(TARGET_IDX, SIZE)
```

Comment: Thank you
What I want to do is to move doublespinbox fields according to the position of the relevant numeric columns of the tablewidget after a resizeToContents